# How can I start X11 only for a single application?

Tags: raspbian, xorg, chromium

I am planning to use my RPi only for one application, which needs X server to be started.

This application is chromium, which requires A LOT of resources already.

I would like to start only the bare minimum (X server) to display chromium in `--kiosk` mode (fullscreen, can't exit, don't show desktop or anything else)

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Would iceweasel (firefox in disguise) be acceptable instead of Chromium which trades memory for speed?

Comment: You should be able to start X with `xinit -e chromium-browser -- ./Xorg -l -c`

Answer (score 17):

You can apply hildred's suggestion permanently by creating a `~/.xinitrc` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec chromium --kiosk
```

This will then be applied if you are using a graphical login, so that you do not have to boot to console.  To test it from the console, try `startx` with no arguments.

Comment: to be more frugal with your memory use exec on the last line of your .xinitrc so you don't have a extra shell lying around using memory/swap

Comment: @hildred - just curious, approximately how much memory does a shell require?

Comment: @cwd You can get an idea with `ps -o pid,rss,cmd -C bash`.  The RSS is in kB, it's probably 3-4000, but if you then look at `top -p [pid]` where pid is one of the ones reported by ps, you'll probably see 75% of that is shared (RSS vs SHR).  So an extra shell takes a MB or two of RAM.  I've edited hildred's suggestion into the answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
startx chromium --kiosk --
```

startx is a wrapper for xinit which starts an xserver and one client program. It should do exactly what you want.

Comment: [1:1:13070520614:ERROR:nss_util.cc(692)] Failed to load NSS libraries. (chromium:3191): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: