# Run Chromium (in Kiosk mode) Without Startx Loading the Desktop

Tags: raspbian, debian, web-server, chromium, raspi-config

I've tried to follow the answer from this topic but didn't work: [Run a GUI without the desktop](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12606/run-a-gui-without-the-desktop)

I have startx running automatically when my raspberry boots thanks to *raspi-config*, but now I need one more thing:

When X starts, I do not want it to open the desktop (i.e., show desktop icons, the desktop bottom bar, etc...), but just want it to run chromium like this:

```
chromium --kiosk http://localhost/
```

Probably it will be a bit faster opening chromium without having to load the entire desktop.

How can I make startx behave like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start X11 only for a application](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/start-x11-only-for-a-application)  The answers there should work, i.e., there will be no desktop environment or window manager, so no icons, taskbars, menus, or anything other than a mouse cursor. You may also be interested in this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9215/how-to-set-up-kiosk-mode-in-raspbian although the focus there is how to boot to and shutdown from a kiosk style application.