# Running Pascal application on Raspberry Pi without desktop environment

Tags: screen, gui, desktop

I am developing a GUI for an embedded Raspberry Pi. To make the Pi run faster and to be more efficient, I was thinking about deleting the default desktop environment from Raspian Stretch.

My question is whether the Pascal GUI app, which will be compiled through FPC and Lazarus to a Linux ARM executable, would run without the desktop environment. Will I be able to launch it through command line and see the GUI pop-up?

Thanks,

Sid.

Comment: First, why not try a simple program and find out. second, you think that you will be able to make a file that will perform faster than the heavily optimized GUI?

Comment: If you're writing to the framebuffer yourself and not using window manager routines, then yes, otherwise - obviously no.

Comment: have you considered this solution: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12606/run-a-gui-without-the-desktop

Comment: @flowtron No, (I think you read this in the dupe already, but to be clear for posterity...) you can use the X server without either a window manager or a DE.  This is probably preferable to the framebuffer since you can still use normal GUI libs.