# Can i make xserver stopped immediatelly when the application exits?

Tags: raspbian, python, xorg

According to the example from:

> [How can I start X11 only for a single application?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/how-can-i-start-x11-only-for-a-single-application)

I'm running python script that shows Tkinter frame by invoking:

```
startx ./script.py
```

... when the script is done, it exits with:

```
root.destroy() # Tk() from Tkinter
sys.exit(0)
```

... however X server seems still to be running (blank screen is displayed and I have to use *Ctrl+C* to get access to the console back).

**How can i make xserver stopped immediatelly when following application exits?**

EDIT: I've noticed that if i didn't use MyThread (but e.g. timer handler method), closing X windows session works fine. Also this script finishes properly when run (tested) on Windows.

Code with issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import threading
import time
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH

SCREEN_RES = "1024x600"
DELAY = 1000
TK_ROOT = Tk()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        try:
            print "Entering MyThread..."
            time.sleep(3)

            print "Exiting MyThread..."    
            TK_ROOT.destroy()
            sys.exit(0)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()


# noinspection PyAttributeOutsideInit
class SysInfo(Frame):
    mt = MyThread()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="gray")

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

        self.after(DELAY, self.on_timer)
        self.mt.start()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.parent.title("SomeFrame")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    def on_timer(self):
        print("Timer fired.")
        self.after(DELAY, self.on_timer)


def main():
    TK_ROOT.geometry("%s+0+0" % SCREEN_RES)

    SysInfo(TK_ROOT)
    TK_ROOT.mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *flipping manual*, which I hope you have found the chance to read, normally `startx(1)` will look in order for `~/.xinitrc` then in the xinit library directory for a system default `xinitrc` script to run - but as you have provided command line **client** arguments instead (`./script.py`) that is used instead. You might find it instructive to look for the system wide script for clues as to how things are normally done.

I think you may get somewhere with further arguments *after* a `--` on the line that you use, arguments after that symbol are **server** arguments, one of which may be relevant is `-terminate` which according to the X server command line help:

> causes the server to terminate at server reset, instead of continuing to run.  This overrides a previous -noreset command line option.

Perhaps this can give some possible pointers...